# How does Azure handle TEMPDB on the local SSD when using WSFC to support an always on availability group?

Tags: azure, cluster, ssd, tempdb

How does Azure handle TEMPDB on the local SSD (drive D:) when using WSFC to support an always on availability group?  I know that the local SSD, where it's recommended to place TEMPDB, is erased during restart... and that a PowerShell script is used on reboot to then recreate the folders/permissions before it then starts the SQL Server services... but if I wanted to then later add WSFC and create a cluster with another Azure VM... to support an always on availability group... how are the cluster services managed?  I don't think I can start the cluster services until the folders/permissions are created right?  I can't find any article that seems to tell me for sure?